# Format for Changing CSS using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Div on my web-page where if someone hover overs it, I want to change the color of the text on all links in the parent Div.  When there is a hover-over, I call the function highlight.  However, the following code does not seem to work.  I think there is a syntax issue because highlight2 works just fine (but doesn't achieve my main goal of changing the color of text.

```
function highlight(el) {
    $(el).parent().css('a:link', "{color:#28A8C8;}");
    $(el).parent().css('a:visited', "{color:#28A8C8;}");
}

function highlight2(el) {
    $(el).parent().css("background", "#FFFFFF");    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's css() method (when setting) requires the first parameter to be a css property and the second to be a value: http://api.jquery.com/css/. You're passing in the node-type you'd like modified rather than the css property you'd like modified. If you're trying to change the color of links inside `$(el).parent()` then you should use:

```
function highlight(el) {
    $(el).parent().children('a:link').css('color', "#28A8C8");
    $(el).parent().children('a:visited').css('color', "#28A8C8");
}
```

If you're trying to change the color of `$(el).parent()` itself (assuming that `$(el).parent()` is a link) then you just need to:

```
 $(el).parent().css('color', "#28A8C8");
```

(no need to differentiate between visited and not visited because you're setting the same color)

Comment: +1, though OP might want to use `.find()` instead of `.children()` if there are anchor elements that aren't immediate children of the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben D said, you have a specific syntax issue with your current code because jQuery's `.css()` function is expecting the first parameter to be the name of a CSS property, not a selector, and the second parameter should be the applicable value.

I'd like to suggest a better way to do the same thing though: add something like the following to your stylesheet:

```
div a:link, div a:visited { color:#defaultcolorhere }
div.highlight a:link, div.highlight a:visited { color:#28A8C8 }
```

Then you can change the colours by adding the "highlight" style to the parent div:

```
$(".hoverdiv").hover(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
}, function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass("highlight");
});
```

(If you give the divs you are hovering over a common class such as "hoverdiv" it makes them easy to select.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zSuS8/